# AU crackling while new view is displayed

Tags: iphone, multithreading, ios, audio, audiounit

On iPhone, I'm using an AudioUnit as a tone generator. Works fine.

However, when I flip the view (turn the back side forward to display an info screen), during the transition the generated tone crackles, both in Simulator and on Device. This happens only when the flipside view is displayed for the first time. Subsequent flips don't crackle.

The flipside view contains a `UIWebView` displaying a local HTML file. (I didn't come up with another way to display rich text.) Maybe I should try to pre-render the view. How can I do this?

Or should I put the audio generation in a different thread? I thought, AUs are called asynchronously—as needed— anyway.

Comment: Does it crackle when you change views without animation?

Comment: How are you setting up your render callback?

Comment: Yes, it crackles even when I switch off the animation. And it crackles only during the very first time I use the view.  I've read that moving UI things away from the main thread is strongly discouraged, and my audio Render method is running in its own thread anyway.

Comment: I set my render callback by setting `inputProc` of my `AURenderCallbackStruct` to my render function. Everything is set up with `AudioUnitSetProperty`.

Comment: Can you create the view of the "back side" when the app starts?